# React child component not rendering when parent first mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to react. I've got a Class Component that makes an api call, sets the component state, and maps the data to render a grid of pokemon. Within that map(), I want to nest another map() that passes the data via props to a child component:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

import PokeCard from './PokeCard'

const pokedexList = [
    { index: 1, generation: 1, pokemon: [] },
    { index: 152, generation: 2, pokemon: [] },
    { index: 252, generation: 3, pokemon: [] }
];

const fetchPokemon = (index) => {
    const fillPokemonList = [];
    for(var i=index; i<=index+8; i++){
        axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`)
        .then((res) => {
            fillPokemonList.push(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log('Pokedex Axios: ', err));
    }
    return fillPokemonList;
}

class Pokedex extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = { pokedex: pokedexList }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getPokemon()
    }
    getPokemon(){
        const copyList = this.state.pokedex;
        copyList.forEach(i => {
            i.pokemon.push(fetchPokemon(i.index))
        });
        this.setState(copyList);
    }
    render(){
        const {pokedex} = this.state;
        const genList = pokedex[0].pokemon.length ? (
            pokedex.map(gen => {
                return(
                    <div className="pokemon" key={gen.generation}>
                        <h5>Generation {gen.generation}</h5>
                        <div className="container">{gen.pokemon[0].map((i) => ( <PokeCard pokemon={i} key={i.id}/> ))}</div>
                    </div>
                )
                })
        ) : (<div>No Pokemon Found :(</div>)
        return(
            <div>
                <div>{genList}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Pokedex
```

This renders the PokeCard (below) only on the second time the Pokedex Component is mounted.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const PokeCard = ({pokemon}) => {
    return(
        <div className="card hoverable">
            <Link to={'/poke-details/' + pokemon.id}>
            <img src={pokemon.sprites.front_default} alt={`${pokemon.name} front`} />
            <h5>{pokemon.name}</h5>
            </Link>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PokeCard
```

Comment: first mistake you are doing is while assigning the state value. 
You should rather do like this :    `this.setState({ pokedex: copyList })`

Comment: Another thing you are not doing correct is the `fetchPokemon` function, it will always return the empty list, because you are calling a rest api, which is asynchronous, either you should use async/await or you should return promise from there and subscribe to it where you need the actual value.

Comment: I don't see where I'm mutating the state directly, I'm using ```const copyList```, setting it equal to state, then calling this.setState on that...?

Comment: `const copyList = this.state.pokedex;` - this is not copying the state. You are just storing a reference to `pokedex` array into another variable.

Comment: I see...I changed it to ```const copyList = [...this.state.pokedex]```, is that enough to avoid directly mutating the state?

Comment: `[...this.state.pokedex]` - this will create a new array but the underlying objects in the array are same. You can use `.map()` method to return a new array that contains same objects but the one object that needs to be updated should be a new object that can be created using property spread syntax: `{...obj, prop: newValue}`

Comment: Instead, I set ```copyList = pokedexList```, however the props in the PokeCard still aren't triggered on initial render. Any ideas about this?

Comment: I assume [this is what you are trying to do](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-cohen-z16ik?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: I see now how you separated the tasks of mapping the state and setting the state using that variable that you explained in your previous comment and I failed to understand. Thank you!